# Why a member of mongodb keep RECOVERING?

Tags: mongodb, database

I set up a replica set with three members and one of them is an arbiter.

One time I restart a member, the member keep RECOVERING for a long time and did not be SECONDARY again, even though the database was not large.

The status of replica set is like that:

```
rs:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs",
        "date" : ISODate("2013-01-17T02:08:57Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "192.168.1.52:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 67968,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1358388479000, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-01-17T02:07:59Z"),
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "192.168.1.50:29017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 107,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-01-17T02:08:56Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "192.168.1.50:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 3,
                        "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                        "uptime" : 58,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1358246732000, 100),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-01-15T10:45:32Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-01-17T02:08:55Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0,
                        "errmsg" : "still syncing, not yet to minValid optime 50f6472f:5d"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to have an ARBITER go into RECOVERING state? What is it recovering if it does not hold data and is only an Arbiter without a journal? None of the data files seem to be growing and its been stuck in this state for hours.

Answer (score 9):

I had exact same issue: Secondary member of replica stuck in recovering mode.
Here how to solve the issue:

1. stop secondary mongo db
2. delete all secondary db data files
3. start secondary mongo

It will start in startup2 mode and will replicate all data from Primary

Comment: I have the same problem. but in my case, the secondary is 24h delayed. If I delete it and start again, will it recover the state 24h before? my local db size 21G now.

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed the issue by following the below procedure.

## Step1:

Login to different node and remove the issue node from mongodb replicaset. eg.

`rs.remove("10.x.x.x:27017")`

## Step 2:

Stop the mongodb server on the issue node 
`systemctl stop mongodb.service`

## Step 3:

Create a new new folder on the dbpath
`mkdir /opt/mongodb/data/db1`
Note : existing path was /opt/mongodb/data/db

## Step 4:

Modify dbpath on /etc/mongod.conf or mongdb yaml file 
`dbPath: /opt/mongodb/data/db1`

## Step 5:

Start the mongodb service
`systemctl start mongodb.service`

## Step 6:

Takebackup of the existing folder and remove it

`mkdir /opt/mongodb/data/backup
mv /opt/mongodb/data/db/* /opt/mongodb/data/backup
tar -cvf /opt/mongodb/data/backup.tar.gz /opt/mongodb/data/backup
rm -rf /opt/mongodb/data/db/`

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if replication has been broken for a while and on the slave it's not enough data to resume replication.

You would have to [re-sync the slave](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) either by replicating data from scratch or by copying it from another server and then resume it.

Comment: I know this is old but I just need to confirm, as I could not find it anywhere else. Does this work with a Sharded cluster of replicasets?

Answer (score -2):

Check mongodb documentation for this issue https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#replica-set-auto-resync-stale-member

Comment: While your link may answer the question, it is always best to include an overview on the answer. Links can be moved or deleted and your answer becomes useless.